# yii2 advanced не сохраняются данные в БД

Tags: yii2

Всем привет, я новичок в yii и я сгенерировал код для связи OneToMany и у меня во views есть форма с возможностью обновить или сохранить данные в Бд, но они никак не сохраняются помогите разобраться пожалуйста

```js
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "authors".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $patronymic
 * @property string $surname
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 *
 * @property Books[] $books
 */
class Author extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'authors';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'patronymic' => 'Patronymic',
            'surname' => 'Surname',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Books::className(), ['id_author' => 'id']);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

```css
/**
 * AuthorController implements the CRUD actions for author model.
 */
class AuthorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all author models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()

    {
        $books = Author::find()->one()->getBooks()->asArray()->all();

        $searchModel = new SearchAuthor();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'books' => $books
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single author model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new author model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Author();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing author model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing author model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the author model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Author the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Author::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Author */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="author-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'patronymic')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?/*= $form->field($model, 'created_at')->textInput() */?><!--

    --><?/*= $form->field($model, 'updated_at')->textInput() */?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: `[['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],`

Comment: Я эту строку пробовал убрать не помогло

Comment: Какие данные не сохраняются? Если из связной таблицы, то их надо дополнительно сэйвить или через метод ->link() сохранять.

Comment: У меня не работало сохранение из-за behavior но почему пока не могу понять